# JQM 1.4.1 What files should I include in my HTML5 manifest file for offline use?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am building an offline Html5 App and I have to prepare my manifest file for caching all files I am using.In previous releases of JQM I just included:

jquery.mobile-x.x.x.min.js, jquery.mobile-x.x.s.min.css, the 2 icon files and the spinner.gif....And my App worked just fine...

Now it turns out that JQM 1.4.1 includes a bunch of files that I don't know if I have to cache them all?

What should I do with all these files?

Do I have to include them all in my manifest file?

[image: Pic of the new files of jqm 1.4.1]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a thorough answer but no, you don't need both the regular and "minified" version of all those files. The .min.* files should theoretically load a bit faster and are worth bundling into the cache manifest. Also if you are targeting multiple device formats, you might want both the PNG and SVG images. However if you are targeting a single device profile (as we are) you can probably isolate only the image format that you want. The default is now SVG with PNGs as backup for browsers that don't support vector images fully.